# excel data to json using nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, xls

here i need to convert my excel to json,since i have been in the right path file only.While running it shows a following error:

[TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter]Any help?

node_x = require("xls-to-json");
var stack = new Error().stack;

```
      try{
     node_x({
      input: "Book1.xls",  // input xls 
      output: "output.json" // output json 

    }, function(err, result) {



          if(err) {

             console.error(err);
                     } else {


    console.log(result);
        }

         }); 

    }catch(e){
         console.log("ssfffs");
         console.error(e);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the sheet name as well

```
    node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
  node_xj({
    input: "Book1.xls",  // input xls 
    output: "output.json", // output json 
    sheet: "sheetname"  // specific sheetname 
  }, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
```

Comment: @user4223185 for once try the same code with some other xls file to see that does it give that error in that case also.

Comment: Yupe...same error checked with another xls file and check its data type ,it shows string